# Android AppChooser connection fails

Tags: android-core, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I installed the OSRF AppChooser on my android tablet and started the roscore on my robots computer (sample IP 123.456.789.123). Then I tried to connect from the AppChooser to the computer by using its IP adress in the above format. Doing so, the tablet can't connect and I get an error underneath the button for the robot that says: "java.lang.ClassCastException:java.lang.Integer canno be cast to java.lang.String".
As I can't find my computer in the network by its domain name using the computer name instead of the IP gives the error "java.lang.RuntimeExcption: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "....": No address associated with hostname".
How do I have to enter a IP adress so that the AppChooser can connect to the robot's computer?
The connection itself is working as I can connect to the roscore without troubles from Rviz for Android. There I use the same IP and port and everything works fine.

Best Wishes Johannes

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65848/android-appchooser-connection-fails/) by [Johannes Mayr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4705/johannes-mayr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2013-06-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jonathan K.](https://answers.ros.org/users/5287/jonathan-k./) on 2013-07-02**:
I'm having the exact same problem, what tablet do you have? I have a Nexus 10, and no other android devices to test it on at the moment.

**Comment by [Johannes Mayr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4705/johannes-mayr/) on 2013-07-03**:
I'm having a Galaxy 10 tablet. But I do have the same problems with my GalaysS Phone. I do not think that this issue is related to the tablet itself. To me it looks like a domain name table problem which I do not know how to solve without rooting the tablet (which is not possible)

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2014-03-19**:
Did anyone find out how to solve this problem? I've tried IP address, DNS, different formats and all end up with issues as mentioned

**Comment by [Maik](https://answers.ros.org/users/21248/maik/) on 2014-12-27**:
Hi,

did anybody solved this issue.
The ROS groovy AppChosser (from Play Store) running on my Android seems not be able to connect to my roscore.
Its shows "Unknown http://192.168.1.48:11311/ java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.integer: cannot cast to java.lang.string".

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible that I can only connect via a fully qualified domain name?
If so, how can I set the hosts file on a tablet without root access?
I think thats not possible and the only solution is to add my IP an a DNS server?

Thanks Johannes

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Mayr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4705/johannes-mayr/) with karma: 81 on 2013-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0